# how to convert a binary string into two's complement and IEEE in C

Tags: c, string, binary, floating-point

SO I have been tasked to write a program that scans in two 32-character binary strings from the user, which will always be 32 characters long. After reading the numbers in, i'm supposed to ask the user which format they would like the strings to be represented in either Two's complement, or IEEE floating point format. The format of the string will determine the numerical value of the string. After which, it is going to be used in a simple math problem, and converted to Octal, Decimal and Hex respectively.

What I am not sure about, is how to convert the 32-character string into two's complement and IEEE floating point respectively. I've tried looking up how to do so, but all of the explanations are above and beyond my understanding of C (which is relatively new to me).

This is a sample binary string in its respective representations:

Binary String: 01000000010010001111010111000011

Format: (Int) for Twos complement, or (Float) for floating-point.

Twos complement representation: 1078523331

Floating-point representation: 3.14

Comment: Looks like homework. What did you try ?

Comment: Its bonus work I asked my professor for, since I didn't have a firm understanding of C. But I tried swapping the binary 0's into 1's and vise-versa, counting up the 1's and then doing (2^i) based on how many 1's were present after the swap.

Comment: IEEE is an association of professionals: the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (https://www.ieee.org ). You cannot easily convert a binary string to an institute of electrical and electronics engineers.

Answer (score 0):

How a binary value is interpreted is duty of the representation, not how you store the value itself.

What I mean is that, once you have a 32 bit binary value, you don't need to "convert" it, you need to interpret it according to a specific codification.

Storing the value in an type appropriate variable is enough for your purpose. So if you store this value directly in a `float` variable (assuming `sizeof(float) == 4`) will yield the correct interpretation according to IEEE and so on.

Comment: Okay, but would storing the binary value in a Int also work for twos complement?

Comment: Since `int` is already interpreted as a two's complement number then yes. Always assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`, otherwise you'd need to pad the higher bits with the sign bit.

Comment: but when you assign it to a "float" or an "int" it just changes the value of the orig. binary value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Read the convert the "binary string" into a `long` using `strtol(...,..., 2)`.  Union the resultant `long` with a `float` and print the desired format.

When printing a `float`, be certain to print with enough precision to provide meaning results: `"%f"` will not do.

```
#include <float.h>
#ifndef FLT_DECIMAL_DIG
#define FLT_DECIMAL_DIG 9
#endif

void display(const char *binary_string, char mode) {
  union {
    long i;
    float f;
  } u;
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  u.i = strtol(binary_string, &endptr, 2);
  if (errno || endptr == binary_string) {
    printf("Bad binary string '%s'\n", binary_string);
  }
  switch (mode) {
    case 'I' : printf("32-bit 2's %ld\n", u.i); break;
    case 'F' : printf("float      %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, u.f); break;
    default: printf("Bad mode '%c'\n", mode);
  }
}


display("01000000010010001111010111000011", 'I'); // 1078523331
display("01000000010010001111010111000011", 'F'); // 3.14000010e+00
```

Assumptions: `sizeof(long) == sizeof(float)`.

Comment: In "Display" what is the "Const Char" variable that we're passing?

Comment: @Shika see lower portion of answer for an example: The "binary string" `display("01000000010010001111010111000011", 'I')`

Comment: I tried the above code that you supplied, and kept receiving an error regarding "FLT_DECIMAL_DIG 9" not being declared, so i just hard coded it into the "display" method as a float. I also am having an issue where the format (mode) will not display correctly, i'm having it passed into the display method through a set of two if statements, which call the "display" method with the correct format. But when I run it, it automatically displays the the format is "bad" and gives me a set of characters. I'll supply the code that i've written if you don't mind taking a look at it.

Comment: @Shika Append your additional info to your post.

Comment: @Shika BTW: your trouble about FLT_DECIMAL_DIG is a concern.  For now, just use `case 'F' : printf("float      %.*e\n", 9 - 1, u.f); break;`

Comment: uh...I would append the info to the post...but my code randomly added thousands of random symbols...And i have no idea why...So i'm re-writing everything..I'll try and do your fix and see if it works that way.